# preciso que retorne nome ao clicar na lista

Tags: java, android

Estou recriando uma de minhas activitys para funcionar com Action Bar, 
com muita ajuda do senhor @Wakin consegui fazer isso funcionar:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gerenciamento);

    abrebanco();
    buscardados();
    gerelista();
    //String[] tabelas = tab.toArray(new String[tab.size()]);

    List<String> l = getgeraList();

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, l);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);



}

private List<String> getgeraList() {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToLast();
    int x=cursor.getCount();
    int y=0;
    while(y<x){
    //nextdado();   
        l.add(retornadado());
        dadoanterior();
        y++;

    }
    return l;
}
```

preciso retornar o conteúdo do que estava escrito no listview que foi selecionado pelo usuário.

o problema que a função:

```
 lv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

da erro. além disso não consigo pegar o conteúdo da lista.

Comment: Poderia dizer qual erro dá?

Comment: ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2110

Comment: @Joannis Isso não é o erro, é o método onde ocorre o erro. O log de erro compreende várias linhas do logcat e deve ser colado na própria pergunta (para isso edite a pergunta e cole as linhas de log).

Comment: não rola mais pois alterei o programa já e esta funcionando. grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando utilizar o `onClickListener` para selecionar um item específico de uma `ListView`.

O [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) serve para a View inteira, não importa em qual item você clica.

Por sua vez, o [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) você consegue selecionar um item específico do seu Adapter dentro da sua `ListView`, retornando o seu `Adaper` e a posição clicada.

Em código:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Selecione o objeto através do adapter da sua lista
            String lista = (String) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);         
            Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar2.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("tabbanco", lista);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Com muito custo consegui da seguinte forma

```
public class gerenciar2 extends ActionBarActivity{
    boolean editar=false, adcionar=false, remover=false;
    SQLiteDatabase Banco = null;
    Cursor cursor;

    String tabbanco="Tabela1";
    TextView gerenciar;
    ListView lista;
    ArrayList<String> tab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gerenciamento);

        abrebanco();
        buscardados();
        gerelista();


        List<String> l = getgeraList();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, l);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    String lista = ad.getItem(position); 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar2.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("tabbanco", lista);
                    gerenciar2.this.finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private List<String> getgeraList() {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToLast();
        int x=cursor.getCount();
        int y=0;
        while(y<x){ 
            l.add(retornadado());
            dadoanterior();
            y++;

        }
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: Uma pergunta importante: você entendeu a diferença entre `onItemClickListener` e o `onClickListener` ?

Comment: não. =( para lista o onclicklistener não funciona 
mas não sei o porque se puder me explicar eu agradeço

Comment: Vou responder com a explicação!